# securityexception was unhandled

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, json.net, foursquare

I am simply trying to parse json using the foursquare venues API and make make some location visible in a list box in my windowphone application but I keep getting the error securityexception was unhandled when I run this line of code.

var providerResult = (Venues.RootObject)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

in

```
 private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Error == null) {

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result))) {
                DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Venues.RootObject));
                var providerResult = (Venues.RootObject)dataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(stream);

                if (providerResult == null) {
                    MessageBox.Show("No location were found");
                }
                else {
                    locations.ItemsSource = providerResult.response.venues;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried deserializing object using var providerResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Venues.RootObject>(e.Result); (no mem stream and stuff)?

Comment: Now its telling me System.MethodAccessException was unhandled

Comment: Oh I think I know what the problem is :( I forget to set my class to public. smh Thanks @igrali